# How to get all events in Azure Time Series Embed Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I have the JSON Request for Time Series Insights REST API as follows:

```
JObject contentInputPayload = new JObject(
                new JProperty("top", new JObject(
                    new JProperty("sort", new JArray(new JObject(
                        new JProperty("input", new JObject(
                            new JProperty("builtInProperty", "$ts")
                        )),
                        new JProperty("order", "Asc")
                    ))),
                    new JProperty("count", getTelemetry.RequestedEventCount)
                )),

                    getPredicateSingle(getTelemetry.PropertyName, getTelemetry.PropertyValue),
                new JProperty("searchSpan", new JObject(
                    new JProperty("from", Convert.ToDateTime(getTelemetry.FromDateTime)),
                             new JProperty("to", Convert.ToDateTime(getTelemetry.ToDateTime)))));
```

I can limit the number of events using the count property.  If I leave it blank I get a ***400 Bad Request***.  How can I request all events within that timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the inner exception when you leave it blank.

Max response size for GetEvents, GetSeries,AggregateSeries is 16MB and don't know if you are hitting the maximum cap or not.

Please refer to the documentation  here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/rest/api/time-series-insights/preview-query

400 InvalidInput    The entity size is more than the maximum allowed size '16,384'. ObjectSizeExceededLimit .